# How to source control configuration in aws service such as `s3`, `cloudfront` configuration?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudfront

I am using `s3`, `Cloudfront` to manage cache used by my web application. There are some configuration is done through aws console such as `origin`, `behaviour`, `permission` etc. I wonder whether these configuration can be set under my git repository so that I can source control them. And I can also add it on my `CI/CD` for testing and deploying.

Comment: You should look at services which let you deploy your infrastructure as code. AWS has CloudFormation for that, but Terraform is also a pretty common alternative.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To maintain your infrastructure changes in source control, you have to define your infrastructure in code. There are a couple of solutions available for that.

**CloudFormation**
AWS provides CloudFormation scripts where you can define your infrastructure defined using JSON or YAML.  This also supports tracking the changes, where if you do a change to CloudFormation and update the changes, AWS tries to update only the new changes done in CloudFormation keeping rest of the resources intact if possible.

For more information refer [AWS CloudFormation CloudFront Distribution Templates](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-cloudfront-distribution.html).
**AWS CLI**
Another option is to use AWS CLI scripts, this is more straightforward since it will be basically several shell scripts that include commands to create the infrastructure.

For more information refer [AWS CLI CloudFormation commands](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/cloudformation/index.html).

**AWS SDK: Write a Code Snippet**
It is also possible to write a code snippet using AWS SDK to provision the CloudFront and resources with the language you prefer.

For more information refer [AWS SDK for NodeJS CloudFront API Reference](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/CloudFront.html)(Or you can find SDK for other languages as well).

Above approaches allow committing the infrastructure changes to source control and keep track of it. However, one limitation of this is that there is no way of knowing what will exactly happen when you apply a change to the infrastructure (No support for Dry Runs).

**Terraform**
This is where tools like Terraform help where you can write your infrastructure using third-party language supported by Terraform which also keep tracking of what has provisioned in AWS. In addition to that, it will show you what will happen if you do a change.

For more details refer [Terraform AWS CloudFront Distribution Module](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/r/cloudfront_distribution.html).

**Serverless Framework Components**
Another open source tool is using Serverless Framework and Components. This is simpler to getting started with but still in its early stage (Serverless Framework is mature but they introduced Components recently).

For more details refer [Serverless Framework AWS CloudFront Component](https://github.com/serverless/components/tree/master/registry/aws-cloudfront).

Answer (score 0):

In order to source control your AWS configuration some additional tools are needed. They are grouped under the term *Infrastructure as Code*. AWS has it's own version of it called [CloudFormation](https://aws.amazon.com/de/cloudformation/). There are also third party tools which can work with other cloud providers too such as [Terraform](https://www.terraform.io).